Methods for testing SQL queries using in memory databases for python lambda functions
I have several pyhon lambda function implementations that uses SQL to innteract with RDS MYSQL instances.These SQL contains multiple joins and I would like to test these SQL joins using some kind of in memory db implementation so I can verify the SQL is working correctly.
I tried with SQLLite  but the sql syntax differs greatly with MYSQL. Is there any kind of in memory implementation for python like H2 for java . I tried the options of running H2 but that requires running and h2 jar file for creating the database which I don't want to do in my python environment. Is there any way I can  do this ?
